# How do i configure two (or more) Antminer S9s on one bitcoin.com account?

Tags: mining-pools, miner-configuration

I just added a second Antminer S9 to my pool. I've been mining with one S9 and bitcoin.com for about a year. in Antminer-1 configuration I have my bitcoin username in the  "Worker" Field / password "123". (works fine). If I enter the same username in my Antminer-2 configuration bitcoin does not seem to see my second Antminer. If I change the Workername in the Worker field, the S9 has no way to access my bitcoin account because the username has changed. It seems the Worker Field entry is functioning as both a Workername and a bitcoin username. The only was I have been able to get both S9s mining is to create a completely separate bitcoin.com account for the second S9 (with a different username). How can I get both S9s mining on the same bitcoin.com account, with different workernames.

Answer (score 1):

If your username is `Antminer` then the username for each machine needs to be like this: `Antminer.foo`, `Antminer.bar`, `Antminer.xx` where `xx` is a unique identifier.

Comment: Thanks Jose. I thought I tried that, but it seems to be working now.